# Pandas - Use column contents to lookup index

Tags: pandas

I have a Pandas Dataframe with relationship between two columns.

```
index| name | manager |
-----+------+---------+
    0| Bob  | Bob     |
    1| Mary | Sue     |
    2| Sue  | Bob     |
    3| Ann  | Sue     |
```

I want to create a new column, looking up the name of each persons manager from the manager column and using the index value for that row for the new series.

```
index| name | manager | mananger_index |
-----+------+---------+----------------+
    0| Bob  | Bob     |               0|
    1| Mary | Sue     |               2|
    2| Sue  | Bob     |               0|
    3| Ann  | Sue     |               2|
```

Now if I go to a pure python solution to the problem, I would do:

```py
# Create a dict from names to row indexes
name_lookup = {}
for row in df.iterrows():
   name_lookup[row.name] = row.index

# Lookup manager's row index for each person's manager.
mananger_indexes = []
for row in df.iterrows():
    mananger_indexes.append(name_lookup[row.manager])

# Save my new column
df['mananger_index'] = mananger_indexes
```

But given that it is Pandas, there's probably a nice one or two line solution out there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This becomes an easy two liner by just translating each section of that python code into its Pandas equivalent.

1. We can get a lookup table to find the index from a value, by switching a series' index and values.
2. Series.map() can take a dictionary like object to lookup values from, rather than just a code lambda to run for each value.

```py
manager_lookup = pd.Series(df.index.values, index=df.name)
df['manager_index'] = df.manager.map(manager_lookup)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can index the managers by name, and use `map`:

```
manager_indexed_by_name = df['name'].reset_index().set_index('name')['index']

df['manager_index'] = df['manager'].map(manager_indexed_by_name)
```

Or one-liner:

```
df['manager_index'] = df['manager'].map(df['name'].reset_index()
                                            .set_index('name')['index'])
```

Output:

```
   name manager  manager_index
0   Bob     Bob              0
1  Mary     Sue              2
2   Sue     Bob              0
3   Ann     Sue              2
```